# How to align a frame to the left in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frame

So I created this GUI in Tkinter. The X, Y and Z labels and entries are in a frame, and I need that frame to be justified to the left (I want it to be next to the "Nombre" entry). I tried the `sticky = "w"` option in the frame but that didn't seem to work. Thank you for the help in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5706A.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that reproduces the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. The most logical choice is to use `grid`, or a combination of `grid` and `pack`. I think the combination makes the most sense -- a frame with the x, y, and z widgets can use `pack`, and then that frame and the other widgets can be laid out using `grid`.

Something like this, perhaps:

```
frame.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)

x_button.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
nombre_label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")
nombre_entry.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="ew")
xyz_frame.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="w")
descripción_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
descripción_entry.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")

x_label.pack(side="left", in_=xyz_frame)
x_entry.pack(side="left", in_=xyz_frame)
y_label.pack(side="left", in_=xyz_frame)
y_entry.pack(side="left", in_=xyz_frame)
z_label.pack(side="left", in_=xyz_frame)
z_entry.pack(side="left", in_=xyz_frame)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Oh I see, what I was lacking was the 'frame.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)' line, I didn't know it existed. Thank you!